# delete the selected item from list

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im using ionic framework and Im trying to create a phone list which can add and delete the user entered phone no.Here the user entered numbers are listed with check box on clicking the add button.When the user selects the check-box and clicks the delete button, he must be able to delete the selected check box phone number.Here the problem is while using the delete button, it doesn't delete the selected check box instead it is deleting the first value entered in the list. So please help me to delete only user selected check-box items.

html code:

```
    <div>
     <ion-checkbox ng-model="phoneno" ng-repeat="y in phonelist">
       <span data-ng-bind="y"> {{y}}</span> </ion-checkbox>
     <button ng-click="remove($index)" value="Delete">Delete</button><br>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>
    <!label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
     <input ng-maxlength="10" ng-model="phone"> <br>
     <button ng-click="add()" value="Add">Add</button><br> 
     <!/label>
    </div>

  </ion-content >

</ion-view>
```

js code:

```
 .controller('PlaylistCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
    })

    .controller('addAdmin',['$scope',function($scope){
           $scope.phonelist=[];
        $scope.add=function(phone){
        $scope.phonelist.push($scope.phone);
            $scope.phone='';
}
            $scope.remove=function(uuid){
              var x=$scope.phonelist[uuid];
              $scope.phonelist.splice(uuid,1);

            }
    }]);
```

Comment: It looks like your `$scope.remove` function is **inside** your `$scope.add` function??

Comment: Seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/9t8kjuw6/. Note that your `remove($index)` function must be **inside** the `ng-repeat` scope, otherwise the `$index` will always be 0

Comment: @devqon: Thanks for the help but Im trying to delete the selected items using single delete button. Thats is the problem ... :(

Comment: But how would the button ever know which one to delete?? If you have one button, which phone do you want to delete when clicking it?

Comment: for that only we use check-box. Using check box we select one or more phone number so when delete button is clicked it should be deleted. @devqon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you mean something else than your code says. You probably want to delete all phones that are checked, when clicking the button. Therefore you don't need the `$index` property, but just loop through the phones and delete the ones that are checked.

You will have to keep track of a 'checked' property of each phone, so you know which are checked. You can do this by using an object which holds the phone information, instead of just a string:

```
<div>
    <!-- ng-model to a property of the phone that keeps track if the phone is checked -->
    <ion-checkbox ng-model="y.checked" 
                  ng-repeat="y in phonelist">
        <span data-ng-bind="y.number">{{ y.number }}</span>
    </ion-checkbox>
    <button ng-click="removeSelected()" value="Delete">Delete</button><br>
</div>
<!-- ng-model to a property of the phone object -->
<input type="text" ng-model="phone.number" />
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.add = function() {
    $scope.phonelist.push($scope.phone);
}

$scope.removeSelected = function() {
    var i = $scope.phonelist.length;
    // reversed loop because you change the array
    while (i--) {
        var phone = $scope.phonelist[i];
        // If phone is checked, remove from list
        if(phone.checked) {
            $scope.phonelist.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

See [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9t8kjuw6/1/)

Or see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7D4r/43/) where I included Ionic

Comment: this works perfect in angularjs but in ionic Im not able to select the check box

Comment: See updated answer. Included a working jsfiddle in ionic

Comment: can you explain your code logic because there is a conflict when I run this in vsCode

Comment: Just take a close look at the working jsfiddle. I can't help you if you with the information 'a conflict in vsCode'

Comment: Your code in jsfiddle works perfect when i applied the same logic as yours, my  phone numbers are getting delete from bottom to up. And  Im not ending up in deleting the specific number which is selected. @devqon

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for my english. I'm foreigner.. 
The problem is that your loop ends before the button, so when the button gets clicked the $index is always 0.
Because its not inside the element "ion-checkbox".

Here is my solution: put ng-click inside the checkbox and call to function with the $index.
And in the js, save the index on a scope var. So if the delete button gets clicked, delete the index that you saved on the previous function.
I hope that i helped.

Comment: Well spotted ! :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're mixing the add and remove functions, try to separate those as below.

```
.controller('addAdmin',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.phonelist=[];
    //Add function 
    $scope.add=function(phone){
        $scope.phonelist.push(phone);
        $scope.phone='';
    }
    //Remove function 
    $scope.remove = function(index){
      $scope.phonelist.splice(index, 1);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: @Rudhara: Try to console the index what you're passing in remove function, it should be the index value like 0,1,2 then it will remove the particular index from the list. See what you're getting when your console. And try to make sure that your HTML is proper.

Answer (score 0):

add the following code in your `controller`

```
$scope.remove = function(index){
  $scope.phonelist.splice(index, 1);
}
```

and that should work

Comment: no its not deleting the specific phone no from the list. It's deleting the first added phone number in the list. @manish